# Is there a way to make sure people cannot access a page unless they have completed a paypal form with php?

Tags: php, javascript, security, paypal, download

I have a file I want to charge users to download with paypal, the paypal account is set up and the redirects work, but I want to keep people from just sharing the download url with their friends so that they have to fill out the paypal form. is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the file outside of your webroot, have users need to login. Setup PayPal's IPN to update user's accounts and allow the user to download the file only if their account is marked as allowed.

Note however that there really is nothing you can do about users sharing the file directly.